# Best way to sign into my Sprint cellphone web account and get account details using Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I would like to create an app on Google App Engine that is able to sign into my Sprint cellphone account and read the total due amount. I sign into my web account at sprint.com. 
 
What is the best way to do this?

The main goal here is to do it in the cloud and not on my computer or cellphone. So that it can sign in with no user interaction and do something with the total amount due. It should really just be requests going to sprint.com.

If it can run in a regular Java app then it should run in Google App Engine. There may be some kind of recording I can do to generate Java code to allow me to log in.
I'm sure though that if I try to replay a request I will have to recalculate security headers somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the selenium webdriver project http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp
They support several programming languages including java and it lets you write jquery style look ups for getting at website info. You aren't bound to FireFox like the example they support the major browsers including chrome. I forget what they call there server service but I know you can deploy this project on a server.

The following is an example from the link above.

```
package org.openqa.selenium.example;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Selenium2Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        // Alternatively the same thing can be done like this
        // driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
        // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
            }
        });

        // Should see: "cheese! - Google Search"
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        //Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Marky17 no problem, have you had any luck getting this setup and trying to login yet?

Comment: I'm actually working on a homework assignment right now and work in the morning. I have not yet. Does the above code example require a browser? I will have to play with it this week yet.

Comment: I'm not sure about the server implementation but running using webdriver does require a web browser. If you are familiar with python I'd suggest getting python 3.4 you can get the package easily using pip which is now standard in python and you can do these calls interactively at the command line.